# Overload local lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

I have a function which is almost the same for `double` and `int` input. I have therefore overloaded the function for the two types. Unfortunately, at the core, there is a difference between the `double` and the `int` variants. Currently, I depend on an overloaded 'core' function for this. To enhance readability I would like to have the overloaded (very short) core functions as part of the function itself, for example using a `lambda` function.

This example below summarizes my current layout (of course the real code is a bit more involved).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

double func_core ( double a, double b ) {
  return a*b;
}

int func_core ( int a, int b ) {
  if ( a==b )
    return 1.;
  else
    return 0.;
}

template <class T> T func ( T a, T b ) {
  return func_core(a,b);
}

int main ( void ) {
  std::cout << func(10 ,20 ) << std::endl;
  std::cout << func(10.,20.) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

For reasons beyond this example I use C++14 (consistent with this I compiled this example using `clang++ -std=c++14 example.cpp`).

Now, I want to get rid of the core-function (`func_core` in this example) because it reduces the readability of my code. Ideally I want to use a `lambda` function that is overloaded within the function itself. I have summarized my thoughts in the example below (**that is not working**).

```
template <class T> T func ( T a, T b ) {
  if ( sizeof(T)==sizeof(int) )
    auto func_core = [](int a,int b){ if (a==b) return 1.; else return 0.; };
  else if ( sizeof(T)==sizeof(double) )
    auto func_core = [](double a,double b){ return a*b; };
  else
    throw std::runtime_error("Overload type not allowed");

  return func_core(a,b);
}
```

Can this be done? Or am I over-stretching?

Comment: And what if `sizeof(T) == sizeof(int)` but `T` is *not* `int` (it could be `float` for example)? How about readability and maintainability? Can you perhaps elaborate on *why* you want to remove the `func_core` overloads? What is the actual problem that will solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Fair point, I added an exception. As to why I want this, I have many of these 'core' functions that belong to one function at a time (as they are similar, but slightly different). The proposed approach would avoid the suggestion that these 'core' functions are re-useable entities.

Comment: I would suggest you to use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, either with C++11 or C++14 you'd to play with beasts like SFINAE or overload resolution to acomplish what you want.

In C++17 however you could use `constexpr if` and merge all the desired functionality into one function template as:

```
template<typename T>
 T func (T const &a, T const &b) {
  if constexpr(std::is_integral<T>::value)
    return (a == b)? 1 : 0;
  else
    return a * b;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6jkffL3MzRmD7VIL)

Comment: Thanks for this good suggestion. Do you also have a suggestion when I don't directly `return` after evaluating what I referred to as `func_core`? E.g. `func_core` adds to some variable in a `for` loop. (In hind-sight I should have included this in the example, but now I would ruin this feed.)

Comment: That should work well in C++11/14, too, if leaving out the constexpr there: `std::is_integral<T>::value` is still a compile time constant and the compiler should optimise away the if and the unused path.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits)

```
template <class T> T func ( T a, T b ) {
    if (std::is_integral<T>::value)
        if (a==b) return 1;
        else return 0;
    else if (std::is_floating_point<T>::value)
        return a*b;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("Overload type not allowed");
}
```

Anyway, i think that best way is avoid lambdas and use normal function overloading.

Comment: This would not yet reach my objective: the variable `func_core` goes out-of-scope before it is evaluated.

Comment: @TomdeGeus true, maybe you should inline the function. It's the same actually, i'll edit